# How to access data- via JQuery?

Tags: javascript

I want create buttons with index inside.

```
let battle_element = `<div class="Battle"> Battle: <button data-index="${battles_list[i].battle_index}">Battle</button></div>`;

$('#battles_list').append(battle_element);

$(".Battle").on("click", function() {
        console.log($(this).data('index'));
})
```

How to get this battle index?

Comment: You add the "click" handler to the `<div>`, not the `<button>`, so `this` is not the button element.

Comment: Damn... You right! Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

Bind the click handler to the `button` instead of the `div`:

```js
let battle_element = `<div class="Battle"> Battle: <button data-index="1">Battle</button></div>`;

$('#battles_list').append(battle_element);

$(".Battle button").on("click", function() {
    console.log($(this).data('index'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="battles_list"></div>
```

If for whatever reason you need it on the `div` instead, use `$.find()` to find the button *inside* the click handler:

```js
let battle_element = `<div class="Battle"> Battle: <button data-index="1">Battle</button></div>`;

$('#battles_list').append(battle_element);

$(".Battle").on("click", function() {
    console.log($(this).find('button[data-index]').data('index'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="battles_list"></div>
```